# JAX-WS error on WSDL file: "Error resolving component 's:schema'"

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

### The Error

I am using wsimport in a Java project to generate sources for three SOAP web services. The first two work fine: I use the JAX-WS Maven plugin to grab the WSDL file and generate corresponding Java source files.

This fails for one web service; I get the following error:

```
[jaxws:wsimport]
Processing: /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl
jaxws:wsimport args: [-s, /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/target/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport, -d, /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/target/classes, -verbose, -catalog, /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml, -wsdllocation, http://erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx?WSDL, -target, 2.0, -extension, -Xnocompile, /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl]
parsing WSDL...


src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 's:schema'. It was detected that 's:schema' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl#types?schema1'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 's:schema' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl#types?schema1'.
  line 80 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl#types?schema1

undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 80 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl

undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 127 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl

undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 142 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl
```

---

### The Culprit

The difference between this WSDL file and the ones that work is what's at the lines noted in the error message, lines 80, 127, and 142:

```
<s:element ref="s:schema" />
```

Note: the root element of the wsdl file defines the "s" namespace thus:

```
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

---

### What I've Tried

I have done my research. It looks like other people have had similar problems, with solutions from "just don't use `<s:element ref="s:schema" />`", to "use an import tag", to some unknowable solution that was apparently on the old java.net forum (before it was taken down, an arson of the modern-day Alexandrian Library of Java knowledge).

- I have tried putting the following import statement just inside the  element that contains the problem  tags: `<s:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" />`. wsimport gives me a new error:

  ```
  [jaxws:wsimport]
  Processing: /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl
  jaxws:wsimport args: [-s, /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/target/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport, -d, /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/target/classes, -verbose, -catalog, /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml, -wsdllocation, http://erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx?WSDL, -target, 2.0, -extension, -Xnocompile, /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl]
  parsing WSDL...


  Element "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}annotation" shows up in more than one properties.
    line 248 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

  The following location is relevant to the above error
    line 242 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

  Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
    line 108 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl

  The following location is relevant to the above error
    line 109 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl

  Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
    line 184 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl

  The following location is relevant to the above error
    line 185 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl

  Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
    line 199 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl

  The following location is relevant to the above error
    line 200 of file:/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Admin/AdminWeb/src/wsdl/erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl
  ```

  Lines 108 and 109 referenced in this error are: (lines 184-5, 199-200 are similar)

  ```
  <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax" />
  <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax" />
  ```
- I have tried upgrading jaxws-maven-plugin from 1.10 to 2.2. Same problem.
- [Here's a possible solution](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/vivekp/archive/2007/05/how_to_deal_wit.html) -- I'm trying to figure out how to implement this using the JAX-WS Maven plugin. Any hints?

---

### Conclusion

Any ideas? Any further information you need? I've omitted the pom.xml and Service.asmx.wsdl files for brevity, but could include them if there's more important information in them.

Thank you!

---

### Addenda

[Here's another person having the same problem](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=437672), if this is helpful to any potential answerers.
[Here's yet another similar problem.](http://www.jitterbit.com/PhpBB/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=319)
I don't really understand [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188755.aspx#S2), but it seems to imply that I have to parse the SOAP XML manually! Horror!

Comment: This may be due to [bug JAXP-14](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXP-14) ... any known workarounds?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved this by adapting [Vivek Pandey's method](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/vivekp/archive/2007/05/how_to_deal_wit_1.html) to Maven, while updating to the jaxws-maven-plugin 2.2. I'll reiterate it here for posterity:

### Summary

Put [this XJB customization file](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/20070228/xsd.xjb) (see below) in your default binding files directory, and set wsimport to bind it and http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd .

### XJB Customization

The contents of the aforementioned XML file, xsd.xjb, that should go in your default binding files directory, is as follows (credit goes to Kohsuke):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          version="2.0">

  <globalBindings>
    <xjc:simple />
  </globalBindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:complexType">
    <class name="ComplexTypeType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:simpleType">
    <class name="SimpleTypeType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:group">
    <class name="GroupType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:attributeGroup">
    <class name="AttributeGroupType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:element">
    <class name="ElementType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:attribute">
    <class name="attributeType"/>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

### POM

Here's the relevant part of my POM file, with changes noted:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- CHANGE: updated groupId and version -->
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution> 
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- CHANGE: added args tag to bind http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd -->
                <args>
                    <arg>-b</arg><arg>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd</arg>
                </args>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlLocation>http://erp-app-devel.srv.mycompany.ca/EgTestReportEngine/Service.asmx.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/Service.asmx.stale</staleFile>
                <!-- CHANGE: added bindingFiles tag to bind XJB customization, located at the default binding files directory, MyProject/src/jaxws/xsd.xjb . -->
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>xsd.xjb</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
            </configuration>
            <id>wsimport-generate-egtestreportengine</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
        <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
        <target>2.0</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the `bindingFiles` section of the pom file and the `-b` command-line argument to `wsimport` do the same thing. Why not combine them? For reference, the`wsimport` command at the provided link is (effectively) `wsimport -b http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd  -b xsd.xjb <TARGET-WSDL>`

Comment: Also, thanks for posting your answer! It works great! Especially, thanks for saving the xjb from bitrot.

Comment: @jpaugh You are very welcome! I am absolutely delighted that, three and a half years later, I was helpful to someone :D

Answer (score 9):

For Nick's solution to work you may have to add these two jvm arguments to your pom.xml
So when encountering those errors:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 11; External DTD: Failed to read external DTD 'XMLSchema.dtd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property.
>
> [WARNING] schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xml.xsd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
>     line 91 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

Just add those to your pom.xml

```
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all

<vmArgs>
    <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all</vmArg>
    <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
</vmArgs>
```

Comment: But depending on external resources is most of the time a bad idea for production systems. What if you need to re-build and cant get to the external resources?

Comment: It is sufficient just adding the <vmargs> block to the pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue fixed it with below command:

`wsimport -b http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd  -b xsd.xjb service.wsdl`

where `xsd.xjb` refers to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          version="2.0">

  <globalBindings>
    <xjc:simple />
  </globalBindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:complexType">
    <class name="ComplexTypeType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:simpleType">
    <class name="SimpleTypeType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:group">
    <class name="GroupType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:attributeGroup">
    <class name="AttributeGroupType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:element">
    <class name="ElementType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:attribute">
    <class name="attributeType"/>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually care about this particular bit of the model data you might be able to use a JAXB bindings file to tell JAXB to map the offending bits to properties whose type is a DOM `Element` rather than actually trying to data bind them into normal JAXB classes. The [unofficial JAXB guide](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Avoid_strong_databinding.html#Mapping_to_DOM) has a section on this technique.

Comment: Thank you. The method that I just detailed in my answer might actually boil down to this; I don't know JAXB well enough to say.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me finally. I am using apache maven cfx plugin

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalJvmArgs>
                                -Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all
                            </additionalJvmArgs>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/generated</sourceRoot> 
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd</extraarg>

                                        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>com.nevado.travelstudio</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                    <!-- <bindingFiles> <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/mybindings.xjb</bindingFile> 
                                        </bindingFiles> -->
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/B2.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

along with these changes I had to create **jaxp.properties** file in ..java/jdk/jre/lib folder
with following property

```
  -Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all
```