# ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor - javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error

Tags: java, jaxb, arcgis

### Background

I'm using wsimport to create what is essentially a Java webservice client, connecting to a .Net webservice that is returning datasets (unfortunately).  To be more specific I'm working on a project (inbound transport) for the GeoEvent Processor suite of ESRI ArcGIS Server 10.2, but I think this might be answered on more general terms in relation to JAXB and WSDL bindings.  Bear with me as I haven't touched Java since college (10+ years).

For purposes of the WSDL, the .Net DataSet is a polymorphic type whose actual layout isn't determined until run time, after the DataSet has been filled with data.  This causes problems when you want to use that webservice with anything but .Net.

After some research I've managed to use **wsimport** to generate from the webservice wsdl.  I was then able to put together a basic proof of concept program that gets results from the webservice as a DOM, then walks that DOM as a nodelist.

Reference:

- [JAX-WS error on WSDL file: "Error resolving component 's:schema'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499860/jax-ws-error-on-wsdl-file-error-resolving-component-sschema)
- https://weblogs.java.net/blog/vivekp/archive/2007/05/how_to_deal_wit_1.html
- The section on Toolkit Bindings and figure 6 in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188755.aspx

My wsimport looks like this (domain names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
C:\Development\ArcGIS\WSDL>wsimport -b http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd -b xsd.xjb -keep -p com.somecompany.services -XadditionalHeaders http://services.somecompany.com/DataRetrieval.asmx?wsdl
```

---

### The Problem

Unfortunately, the same codebase that worked in my proof of concept, getting results from the webservice, fails once I implement in the ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor.  My project is part of an OSGI bundle that the ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor will control.  The error below is as shown in the Apache Karaf log for the GeoEvent Processor.

Based on the error, my understanding is there is a problem with how I did the binding in wsimport, referencing the generic schema per those links I have listed above.  Looks like the generic schema lacks definitions for some of the elements that exist as classes generated by wsimport.  Those classes appear to be properly generated when I check the output from wsimport.

I've not included the WSDL due to posting limitations, but will include in later responses if needed.

### What I'm trying to figure out

- How should this error be interpreted?
- Why does the same wsimport generated code used to access the webservice in my basic proof of concept fail when run in the ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor?
- The error mentions JAXB and SAX, I'm not consciously referencing either of those libraries in the proof of concept or the project for the ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor.  Could it be that the binding/unmarshalling of the webservice is handled differently, with ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor wrapping in JAXB/SAX and the proof of concept not?
- What can I do to resolve this?

  > 1. Use a different, custom, xsd and xjb that spells out the expected schema for the webservice?  I'm not sure exactly how that would be done.
  > 2. Use something other than **wsimport** to generate the webservice reference classes?
  > 3. Tweak something in the java environment for the ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor?
  > 4. Other options?
  > 5. Commit seppuku, then it's not my problem?

---

### The Error

```
2014-09-23 16:10:14,365 | ERROR | ansport Listener | SomeInboundTransport             | 367 - com.somecompany.arcgis.geoevent.transport.inbound.somecompanyInboundTransport - 1.0.0 | Unable to call Webservice
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", local:"element"). Expected elements are <{http://services.somecompany.com/}complexType>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}annotation>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}redefine>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}element>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}include>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}attributeGroup>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}group>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}notation>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}import>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}simpleType>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}attribute> 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)[120:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.6.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy198.getCompanyArcgisData(Unknown Source)[367:com.somecompany.arcgis.geoevent.transport.inbound.somecompanyInboundTransport:1.0.0]
    at com.somecompany.arcgis.geoevent.transport.inbound.SomeInboundTransport.callWebService(SomeInboundTransport.java:184)[367:com.somecompany.arcgis.geoevent.transport.inbound.somecompanyInboundTransport:1.0.0]
    at com.somecompany.arcgis.geoevent.transport.inbound.SomeInboundTransport.run(SomeInboundTransport.java:257)[367:com.somecompany.arcgis.geoevent.transport.inbound.somecompanyInboundTransport:1.0.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 651; unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", local:"element"). Expected elements are <{http://services.somecompany.com/}complexType>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}annotation>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}redefine>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}element>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}include>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}attributeGroup>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}group>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}notation>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}import>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}simpleType>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}attribute>]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:425)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:339)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:784)[91:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:97)[91:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$1.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:812)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_17]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:810)[91:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:644)[91:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:157)[91:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:108)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1667)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1520)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1428)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:658)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)[87:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)[119:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-simple:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)[120:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.6.1]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 651; unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", local:"element"). Expected elements are <{http://services.somecompany.com/}complexType>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}annotation>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}redefine>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}element>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}include>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}attributeGroup>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}group>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}notation>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}import>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}simpleType>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}attribute>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:642)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:101)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.childElement(StructureLoader.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:360)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", local:"element"). Expected elements are <{http://services.somecompany.com/}complexType>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}annotation>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}redefine>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}element>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}include>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}attributeGroup>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}group>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}notation>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}import>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}simpleType>,<{http://services.somecompany.com/}attribute>
    ... 39 more
```

---

### The Code (snippet)

```
import com.somecompany.services.*; //generated by wsimport
import javax.xml.ws.*;
//...

private com.somecompany.services.DataRetrieval myWS;
private com.somecompany.services.DataRetrievalSoap port;

private byte[] callWebService(String userName, String pwd, long dataTimeFrame)
{
    try
    {
        myWS = new com.somecompany.services.DataRetrieval();

        port = myWS.getDataRetrievalSoap();
        com.somecompany.services.AuthSoapHeader mySoapHeader = new com.somecompany.services.AuthSoapHeader();
        mySoapHeader.setUserName(userName);

        //Hash the password then set it for the SOAP header
        String pwdHash = hashMD5(pwd);
        mySoapHeader.setPassword(pwdHash);
        Holder holder = new Holder<AuthSoapHeader>(mySoapHeader);

        Date endTime = new Date();
        Date startTime = new Date(endTime.getTime() - dataTimeFrame);
        XMLGregorianCalendar gcEndTime = dateToGregorianTime(endTime);
        XMLGregorianCalendar gcStartTime = dateToGregorianTime(startTime);

        GetCompanyArcgisDataResponse.GetCompanyArcgisDataResult companyData = port.getCompanyArcgisData(gcStartTime, gcEndTime, holder);

        if( ((AuthSoapHeader)holder.value).getError() != null)
        {
            log.error("Authentication to web services failed!");
            //OSGI stop service
            this.stop();
            return null;
        }else
            log.info("Authentication to web services successful.");

        //Convert the results to a java object and then to a byte array to send to the adapter
        Object companyDataAny = companyData.getAny();
        byte[] companyDataBytes = objectToBytes(companyDataAny);
        return companyDataBytes;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.error("Unable to call Webservice", ex);
        //OSGI stop service
        this.stop();
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

### Environment Specifics

- JDK 7u17 (1.7.0_17) 64 bit.  The ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor is using this version of the JRE, so I'm locked into that version for execution.  Though I've done some development in 1.7.0_51 before I realized that.
- wsimport - JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
- ArcGIS Server 10.2
- ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor Extension
- Karaf (used by ArcGIS Geovent Processor to run OSGI bundles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best answer on this, but it's what I came up with.

The ArcGIS GeoEvent Processor that wrapped my OSGI project appeared to be doing some additional binding/unbinding of the web service that I referenced in my application.  The work-around that I employed to get that .Net (DataSet return values) web service to function in Java just wasn't acceptable to that wrapper from the GeoEvent Processor.

### My Solution

Ultimately what I did was create a secondary .Net web service which took the DataSet values and converted them to JSON, and returned JSON strings.  This removed the problems encountered when attempting to reference DataSet return values from the web service, now I was dealing with a simple JSON string.  The **wsimport** of that JSON web service went smooth, no work-around required.  I tucked the newly imported web service files into my java project and now have no problems.

For Reference on C# DataSet to JSON:

- Using Newtonsoft.Json (http://james.newtonking.com/json).  After playing with a few other libraries for JSON serialization that is what I found worked best for me.
- Newtonsoft.Json is available via NuGet package
- Rick Strahl's site was a big help  http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer