# Generation javacode from WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java, wsimport

I want to generate java-code from this wsdl:
http://www.cbr.ru/CreditInfoWebServ/CreditOrgInfo.asmx?WSDL

I use command:

```
wsimport -d C:\test http://www.cbr.ru/CreditInfoWebServ/CreditOrgInfo.asmx?WSDL -Xnocompile
```

As a result of many such errors

> [ERROR] undefined element declaration 's:schema'
>     line 55 of http://www.cbr.ru/CreditInfoWebServ/CreditOrgInfo.asmx?WSDL

## UPDATE

I tried [undefined element declaration 'xs:schema'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898261/undefined-element-declaration-xsschema)
used the command >>

> wsimport -b http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd -b customization.xjb CreditOrgInfo.wsdl

and got an error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 11; External DTD: Failed to read external DTD 'XMLSchema.dtd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose update

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499860/jax-ws-error-on-wsdl-file-error-resolving-component-sschema, try adding these properties -Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I am able to generate code with your command. My output is provided. Files are generated in the filesystem.

```
> wsimport   -b http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd -b customization.xjb http://www.cbr.ru/CreditInfoWebServ/CreditOrgInfo.asmx?WSDL -Xnocompile
parsing WSDL...

[WARNING] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 's:schema'. It was detected that 's:schema' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but compone
nts from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'http://www.cbr.ru/CreditInfoWebServ/CreditOrgInfo.asmx?WSDL#types?schema1'. If this is the i
ncorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 's:schema' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to
'http://www.cbr.ru/CreditInfoWebServ/CreditOrgInfo.asmx?WSDL#types?schema1'.
  line 55 of http://www.cbr.ru/CreditInfoWebServ/CreditOrgInfo.asmx?WSDL#types?schema1

[WARNING] Ignoring SOAP port "CreditOrgInfoSoap12": it uses non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
You must specify the "-extension" option to use this binding.
  line 2449 of http://www.cbr.ru/CreditInfoWebServ/CreditOrgInfo.asmx?WSDL

generating code...
```